# How to queue requests in PHP

Tags: php, forms, queue

How can I queue url requests in php across multiple users. Suppose there is a form, but I need only 1 submission every 10seconds.

If user1 submits the form at 12:00:01 and then another user submits the form at 12:00:03 he will be queued and his request will be submited at 12:00:11. If third user submits at 12:00:09, then he will be second in the queue and will be processed at 12:00:21.

I could not find any suitable solution for something like this
[image]

Comment: Use a database to store users that are currently in queue.

Comment: That is a non trivial task... Without further details I'd say the clean and robust approach is to accept each request immediately and queue only the task to be performed in a server side queuing system. Then you can use client side triggered ajax long poll requests (or web sockets) to wait for the result of the queued tasks result.

Comment: let me know if my answer helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have various options for queues, among which are the following two:

**1)** using a queue library like **pheanstalk** (which requires **beanstalkd**). It's a queue that uses the TCP protocol (by default on port 11300 though this can be changed easily). It's very well tested, robust, and most importantly opensource:
https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk

**2)** Store your users input in a database, and have your code execute the request every 10 seconds. This option is probably much simpler to execute. You would however also need to create a daemon, which is basically a stand-alone script running in the background processing the information in the queue. For example, lets say that the form page redirects the user to validation.php when the form is submitted and the following php PDO code is executed:

```
 //....
 $sql = "INSERT INTO queue (user_id, process) VALUES (?, ?)";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute([$id, $process]);
 //...
```

You would then have `$id` and `$process` stored at the end of the `queue` table (ALSO lets assume that queue has a PRIMARY KEY called `queue_id` that is set up to be AUTO_INCREMENT). From there, you would have the sand-alone script (daemon) running in the background that would retrieve that data, and process it. For instance:

**worker.php**:

```
<?php
//other code like connecting to the database
while (1)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM queue LIMIT 1; ";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    //code that processes the values obtained from result

    $sql = "DELETE FROM queue WHERE queue_id = {$result['queue_id']}";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);


}
```

**IMPORTANT RECOMMENDATION:**

It would be even better if you used transactions in the above code to guarantee that the selection, processing, and deletion all happen together. If for instance the power goes out on your server (or something similar) when the deletion was about to happen, when restarting the server, your worker.php file would process that file again since it wasn't deleted, however with transactions, that wouldn't be a problem.